# Using a lock in C++ across multiple tasks

Tags: c++, curl, concurrency, mutex

I am not really seeking code examples, but I'm hoping someone can review my program design and provide feedback. I am trying to figure out how do I ensure I have one instance of my "workflow" running at a time.

I am working in C++.

This is my workflow:

1. I read rows off of a Postgres database.
2. If the table has any records, I want to do these instructions:
3. Read the records and transform them to JSON
4. Send the JSON document to a remote Web service
5. Parse the response from the service. The service tells me which records were saved or not saved, based on their primary key.

   - I delete the successfully saved records
   - I log the unsuccessful records (there's another process that consumes the logs and so my work is done).

I want to perform all of this threads using a separate thread (or "task", whatever higher-level abstraction is available in C++), and I want to make sure that if my function for [1] gets called multiple times, the additional calls basically get "dropped" if step 1 is already in flight.

In C++, I believe I can use a flag and a mutex. I use a something like `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` at the top of my method. Then the next line checks for a flag.

```
// MyWorkflow.cpp
std::mutex myMutex;
int inFlight = 0; 

void process() {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(myMutex);
  if (inflight) {
    return;
  }
  inflight = 1;

  std::vector<Widget> widgets = readFromMyTable();
  std::string json = getJson(&widgets);
  ... // Send the json to the remote service and handle the response
}
```

Okay, let me explain my confusion. I want to use Curl to perform the HTTP request. But Curl works asynchronously. And so if I make the asynchronous HTTP call via Curl, my update function will just return and `myMutex` will be released, right?

I think in my asynchronous response handler, I need to call a second function that's in MyWorkflow.cpp

```
void markCompletion() {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(myMutex);
  inFlight = 0; // Reset the inflight flag here
}
```

Is this the right approach? I am worried that if an exception is thrown anywhere before I call markCompletion(), I will block all future callers. I think I need to ensure I have proper exception handling and always call markCompletion().

I am terribly sorry for asking such a noob question, but I really want to learn to do this the right way.

Comment: Instead of mutex you can use semaphore for this. In that case no need to use separate inflight variable

Comment: @RushikeshTalokar It would be a binary semaphore, right? But wouldn't the semaphore itself require a mutex to ensure it's atomically written to?

Comment: What's the purpose of the global shared valued `inFlight`? Your design is basically clean, but you missed some requirements details? How many lines of data in the database table(Estimated the data magnitude)? Your production environment (How many CPU cores, do you use SSD disk)? It's a typical use case for the async concurrent system. Many steps in your design can run in parallel (3,4,5) to achieve the best performance. What framework(something like boost, poco, folly) are you using now?

Comment: This is running on a device with 1-2 cores. Data is on the order of a few megabytes. It does not live long. And there’s no framework.

Comment: @Beebunny yes, It will be binary semaphore & it needs mutex. If you want to notify waiting thread that executing thread is finished, you can use semaphore.